# How can I access a class property in an arrow function passed to a constructor?

Tags: typescript

I defined a class to render authentication methods on a React login page, the interface includes a default render function that I want to override.

```ts
class AuthMethod {
    constructor(initializer: Pick<AuthMethod, 'id'> & Partial<AuthMethod>) {
        Object.assign(this, initializer);
    }
    id!: string;
    text: string = "";
    enabled: boolean = false;
    icon: React.ReactNode = React.Fragment;
    render: () => React.ReactNode = () => (
        <WhiteIconButton key={this.id} disabled={!this.enabled} >
            {this.icon}
        </WhiteIconButton>
    );
}
```

I initialize an array of these for use in a few places (e.g. login form):

```ts
const authMethods: AuthMethod[] = [
    new AuthMethod({
        id: "auth_facebook",
        text: "Sign in with Facebook",
        enabled: false,
        icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebookSquare} />,
        // render: () => this.icon  // This doesn't work
    }),
    new AuthMethod({
        id: "auth_twitter",
        text: "Sign in with Twitter",
        enabled: false,
        icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTwitter} />
    }),
    new AuthMethod({
        id: "auth_google",
        text: "Sign in with Google",
        enabled: true,
        icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGoogle} />
    })
];
```

Later I can render them like this:

```
<div className={classes.socialLine}>
    { authMethods.map(m => m.render()) }
</div>
```

The problem is I can't override the "render" arrow with one that uses the properties of the class, in the Facebook example if I uncomment the "render:" line I get the error message "The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'".

How can I access member properties in the supplied arrow function?

Edit: You can run it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-bhabha-8jdmf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Just uncomment the "render: " line to see the problem.

**Solution:**

Thanks to [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) for providing the answer that arrow functions don't have access to the "this" property (because it's bound to whatever "this" exists where it is created). So the solution is to use a "normal" function (non-arrow). I thought this wouldn't work when the signature in the class definition is an arrow function, but that's not the case and the solution is:

```ts
  new AuthMethod({
    id: "auth_facebook",
    text: "Sign in with Facebook",
    enabled: false,
    icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebookSquare} />,
    render: function() {
      return this.icon;
    }
  }),
```

You can see it in action here: https://8jdmf.csb.app/

Comment: Could you edit this code to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)?  This would help others produce a testable answer.  Without this I can only guess that the issue is that arrow functions do not have their own `this` context and the fix is to use `function(){return this.icon}` instead.

Comment: You can run it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-bhabha-8jdmf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions [do not have their own `this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this), unlike non-arrow functions such as those defined with the `function` keyword.  So any mention of `this` within an arrow function body will actually refer to whatever `this` is referring to in its lexical context, which isn't what you want.

The most straightforward solution here is to abandon arrow functions.  You can either use an anonymous function like `function(){return this.icon}`, or you can use the terser [method syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions):

```
  new AuthMethod({
    render(){return this.icon}, 
    id: "auth_facebook",
    text: "Sign in with Facebook",
    enabled: false,
    icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebookSquare} />
  }),
```

This should work and is arguably the conventional way to represent what you're doing.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that worked - I thought I had to pass an arrow function when the signature in the class definition was one, but that's not the case, this works:  https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-bhabha-8jdmf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark